# App info sharing like iTunes app does

Tags: ios, web, itunes, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I want to share my app Info. programmatically like iTunes app does, like these pics show

When we click on this button

[image]

----------------------------------------------iTunes app load it's info in MFMailComposer like this

[image]

Can we do like this programmatically.

Comment: If you are displaying other apps details your app may get rejected under section 2.25 of the Apple App Store Review Process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like all it does is it opens an MFMailComposerViewController with the body of the message set to some HTML.

Just use [setMessageBody:isHTML:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MFMailComposeViewController/setMessageBody%3aisHTML%3a)

with isHTML set to true.